# Vuex, Is nested mutations / actions is possible?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm wondering if we can use nested mutations / actions inside Vuex (Sorry in advance if my english is bad)

I have code like this:

```
...
mutations: {
    SET_AUTH: (state) => {
        state.auth = true
    },
    SET_PROFILE: (state, payload) => {
        state.profile = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    userLogin: ({ commit }, payload) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Axios.post('/login', payload)
                .then(res => {
                    commit('SET_AUTH')
                    commit('SET_PROFILE', res.data.profile)
                    resolve(res)
                })
                .catch(...)
        })
    }
}
```

Now when things got bigger, I have to scroll 2-3 times up n down to search if I already set the mutations / actions I needed, because it all using 'SET' word, I knew I can reverse the word and order them in descending order (A-Z), like 'AUTH_SET', 'PROFILE_SET', etc...

**but I have an idea, to put it in an object that fits its place**

```
// Example:

...
mutations: {
    user: {
        SET_AUTH: (state) => {
            ...
        },
        SET_PROFILE: (state, payload) => {
            ...
        }
    }
},
actions: {
    user: {
        login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
            //
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

And then when I dispatch an actions, like:

```
this.$store.dispatch('user.login', ...);
```

> Got an error: **Uncaught Error: [vuex] actions should be function or object with "handler" function but "actions.user" in module "user" is {}.**

Is this even possible? because I like it this way, make my code cleaner

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vuex module system and put each module in its own `.js` file, here is the documentation for it:

[vuex modules](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#module-local-state)

for short you can have a file called `user.js` and in it you'll have:

```
export const state = () => ({
   // user related states
});

export const mutations = {
   // user related mutations
};

export const actions = {
  // user related actions
};

export const getters = {
  // user related getters
};
```

then you can dispatch an action from component like this:

```
this.$store.dispatch('user/someAction', payload);
```

and access the states in your component like:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
...
computed: {
  ...mapState('user', ['stateNameOne', 'stateNameTwo']),
}
```

and so on...

also for the mutations when all they're doing is setting a value to a state I'd like to write only one mutation like this:

```
SET(state, { key, value }) {
  state[key] = value;
}
```

now I have only one mutation and in its payload I specify which state I want to update using `key` and my commit would be like this:

```
commit('SET', { key: 'stateName', value: stateValue });
```

here is an article for further information about this topic:

[modules in vuex](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/how-to-structure-a-complex-vuex-store/)

***Edit***

when you are separating each vuex module in its own .js file you have two alternate syntax:

**option 1**: Exporting constants

for example in this directory: `/store/store.js` you'll have:

```
import * as name from '@/store/modules/name.js'
```

and in the module file in this directory: `/store/modules/name.js` you'll have:

```
export const state = { ... } 
export const mutations = { ... }
export const actions = { ... }
export const getters = { ... }
```

**Option 2**: Exporting one Object

in `/store/store.js`:

```
import name from '@/store/modules/name.js'
```

in `/store/modules/name.js`:

```
export default {
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... },
}
```

in both cases your main vuex file can use the imported module like this:

```
export default new Vuex.store({
  modules: {
    name
  },
  state: { ... },
  mutations: { ... },
  actions: { ... },
  getters: { ... },
})
```

I didn't find anything on vuex documentation to reflect what you're trying to do like nested actions and ...

I think the only option here is to separate each module in its own file using one of the options mentioned above and then import them in the main vuex file

Comment: Hello, I'm really sorry for late reply, currently I'm using Vuex modules, but with different methods, single modules but not like your method sir, too many `export` got me really confused, perhaps I really don't like it, but I love your `SET` mutations, so based on my question, is it not possible right?

Comment: I added some additional info to the answer and about your question I didn't find anything in the documentation so I don't think its possible

Answer (score -1):

It literally says that the actions should be a function and you are defining an object like this:

```
actions: {
user: {
    login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
        //
    },
    ...
 }
}
```

You should change the user object and make it a function:

```
actions: {
user_Login: ({ commit }, payload) => {
        //
    },
    ...
}
```